# Salvar multiplas figuras num loop - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estou usando python para análise de dados experimentais. Tenho em uma pasta diversos arquivos de dados que, no script, são agrupados segundo alguns critérios. Uso um laço para ler todos os arquivos da pasta e, dentro do laço, dados de um mesmo grupo são plotados em um mesmo gráfico, salvando os diferentes gráficos ao final do loop.

Isso funciona muito bem para apenas um tipo de plot no laço. Como quero diferentes plots, esse método não funciona pois há superposição de dois gráficos.

É possível salvar diferentes figuras em um laço apenas?

Comment: Olá, Eduardo. O que você quer provavelmente é possível se criar uma imagem em branco para cada novo grupo, mas seria interessante você postar o código para que pudéssemos analisar.

Comment: É recomendado fortemente para sempre mostrar um exemplo mínimo do que se está tentando fazer.

Answer (score 4):

Você não mostrou seu código, mas assumindo que você está usando `matplotlib.pyplot` tal como no [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html), eu sugiro que cada nova figura e/ou cada novo *subplot* seja armazenado em um `dict`, de modo que você possa acessá-lo novamente sempre que necessário:

```
imagens = {}
def obter_subplot(imagem, subplot, *args, **kwargs):
    if not imagem in imagens:
        imagens[imagem] = { '__imagem':matplotlib.pyplot.figure(imagem) }
    if not subplot in imagens[imagem]:
        imagens[imagem][subplot] = imagens[imagem].__imagem.add_subplot(*args,**kwargs)
    return imagens[imagem][subplot]

for arq in iterar_arquivos():
    for grupo in escolher_grupos(arq):
        for subplot,args,kwargs in escolher_subplots(arq, grupo):
            plt = obter_subplot(grupo, subplot, *args, **kwargs)
            # usar plt como se fosse matplotlib.pyplot

for imagem in imagens.keys():
    matplotlib.pyplot.image(imagem) # Troca a imagem corrente
    matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(...) # Salva a imagem corrente num arquivo
```

Esclarecendo:

- O `dict` **`imagens`** mapeia o nome de cada imagem para um outro `dict`, que mapeia o nome de um subplot para o subplot específico. Os parâmetros `args` e `kwargs` permitem que você customize a criação do subplot (ex.: para `subplot(2,1,1)` use `args=[2,1,1]` e `kwargs=None`);
- Substitua os métodos `iterar_arquivos`, `escolher_grupos` e `escolher_subplots` pela sua lógica particular.
- Ao chamar [`matplotlib.pyplot.image`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) passando o mesmo nome da imagem que você criou anteriormente, ele troca a mesma para a "imagem corrente". Isso permite que você a salve em um arquivo da forma usual.

---

<sub>Fontes: [salvando imagem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/matplotlib-save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-so-can-be-used-in-b), [atribuindo a imagem corrente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986567/matplotlib-how-to-set-the-current-figure), [criando subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206335/matplotlib-how-do-i-switch-between-subplots-rather-than-replotting-them-from-s) (todas do SOEN).</sub>