# Quando usar variáveis de instância vs parâmetros?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software

Assumindo que uma classe `A` utilize uma classe `B` (diretamente ou através de uma interface `C` para desacoplar `A` de `C`).

Deixando claro que `A` e `B` são partes independentes, *i.e.*, a relação entre as duas classes não é de composição ou uma agregação óbvia, porém existe uma associação "fraca" em que `A` usa `B` (nesse caso, através do contrato estabelecido por `C`).

Considere os dois exemplos (em Java):

***Exemplo 1** - C como Variável de instância*:

```java
public class A {
    private C c;

    // Não estou discutindo injeção através de construtores vs. getters and setters
    // Apenas assuma que `c` foi inicializado de alguma maneira
    public A(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public metodo1() {
       // faz algo com c   
    }

    public metodo2() {
       // faz algo com c   
    }

    public metodo3() { 
      // não faz nada com c
    }
}
```

***Exemplo 2** - C como parâmetro*:

```java
public class A {

    public metodo1(C c) {
       // faz algo com c   
    }

    public metodo2(C c) {
       // faz algo com c   
    }

    public metodo3() { 
       // não faz nada com c
    }
}
```

A minha pergunta é em que situação devo fazer com que `A` possua uma variável de instância do tipo `C` *vs.* quando devo passar uma instância do tipo `C` como parâmetro para os métodos de `A`?

Em outras palavras: Em que situações a API exposta no *Exemplo 1* seria "melhor" do que a API exposta no *Exemplo 2* e vice-versa? Quais seriam as justificativas para apoiar essa decisão?

Após muitos anos como desenvolvedor eu ainda tomo essa decisão na base do *feeling*. Também reparei que com o passar do tempo a construção do exemplo *2* (que era rara, e prontamente refatorada para *1* no meu código) começou a se tornar mais aceitável e até preferível em boa parte das situações. Porém, até hoje tenho dificuldade em formalizar os motivos que me levam a escolher uma construção ou outra.

Comment: Parte do programa mais perguntas para o Beta

Comment: Pessoalmente, considero essa pergunta meio "ampla demais" meio "não está claro o que está perguntando". Antes de ler sua própria resposta, achava que era uma pergunta conceitual (e formulei a primeira parte da resposta); depois de lê-la, vi que se tratava mais de aspectos práticos (i.e. a "relação natural entre `A` e `B` está clara, mas implementá-la dessa forma traz consequencia negativas") - e formulei a segunda. Sugiro que, se possível, edite a pergunta para torná-la mais específica.

Comment: Olá @mgibsonbr, sugestões para melhor a pergunta são bem vindas. Porém eu infelizmente não estou trabalhando em cima de um exemplo "concreto de código". O problema é que, ao meu ver, existe uma diferença tênue em certas situações. Uma lacuna conceitual e espaço para opinião na hora de decidir entre associações vs passagem de parâmetros repetidamente na API. Para mim uma associação é mais forte e "continua", enquanto a passagem de parâmetros é mais fraca e "discreta" (não sei se fez sentido).

Comment: Bom, minha principal sugestão é tornar mais claro sobre o que a pergunta **não é**. Por exemplo, quando escreve "Assumindo que uma classe `A` utilize uma classe `B`" fica ambíguo se existe ou não relação entre ambas [fora do contexto do método]. Se para fins dessa pergunta assume-se que **não**, que `A` e `B` não se relacionam conceitualmente, seria interessante ter isso explícito na pergunta. Da mesma forma, sua principal motivação pelo que entendi é a criação de uma boa API, e não a modelagem de entidades em classes. Visto por esse foco, pode-se dar respostas mais direcionadas.

Comment: Bem melhor agora! +1, e vou editar minha resposta para torná-la mais concisa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De fato, nenhuma das opções é a ideal. Vou discorrer brevemente sobre cada uma delas e depois propor uma alternativa.

### Opção 1: guardar estado em A

Essa solução, embora deselegante, pode ser viável ao menos em casos onde não há paralelismo (i.e. somente um algoritmo executando em um único thread terá acesso a `A`). Nesse caso, o uso de uma variável representando o "`C` corrente" simplifica bastante o seu uso.

Entretanto, em se tratando de uma API para terceiros, fica difícil prever como a mesma será usada. Tomando como exemplo [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7679/215) que respondi recentemente, o fato da biblioteca [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org) usar uma "imagem corrente" e um "subplot corrente" para direcionar todas as suas operações torna complexo trabalhar com múltiplas imagens e subplots ao mesmo tempo (mesmo na ausência de paralelismo).

### Opção 2: passar C como parâmetro sempre

A maior vantagem aqui é a flexibilidade, a maior desvantagem a verbosidade do código (sempre ter que ficar repetindo a passagem de `c` como parâmetro). Na maior parte do tempo isso é apenas um inconveniente, de modo que essa solução é válida sem reservas. Não é a ideal, mas é válida.

### Opção 3: "currying" de objetos

O conceito de [*currying*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21215/215), quando suportado por uma linguagem de programação, normalmente se aplica a uma única função. Por exemplo, dado `A.metodo1(C, D, E):F` poderia ser fixado o `C` na forma de `curry(a.metodo1, c) -> fn(D, E):F`. Entretanto, isso é de pouca ajuda ao código cliente, já que ele precisará combinar dois ou mais métodos de `A` para realizar sua função.

Entretanto, se extrapolarmos esse conceito para toda a classe `A`, podemos criar uma classe auxiliar `X` que "fixa" a instância de `C` [além do próprio `A`] e expõe somente os métodos de `A` que envolvem a classe `C`. Por exemplo:

```
class X {
    private A a;
    private C c;

    public X(A a, C c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public metodo1() {
        // faz algo com a e c   
    }

    public metodo2() {
        // faz algo com a e c   
    }

    // Sem "metodo3"; somente os métodos em que A e C interagem
}
```

Se conveniente, `A` pode servir como uma fábrica para `X`:

```
class A {
    public X curry(C c) {
        return new X(this, c);
    }
}
```

Dessa forma você simplifica a interface (i.e. cria uma [fachada](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A7ade)) sem ter que "poluir" a classe `A` com a introdução de uma propriedade que não corresponde à relação conceitual [estática] entre as entidades `A` e `C`.

Comment: *Currying* me dá uma saudade brava de Scala e Haskell :). A ideia de criar uma classe auxiliar para amarrar `A` e `C` sem introduzir uma variável de instância é muito útil. Você consegue expor uma API em que uma instância de `A` esteja "vinculada" a uma instância de `C` sem impor esse modelo para `A`. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Algumas referências interessantes sobre o assunto:

## [SOE - Parameter vs. Member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529590/parameter-vs-member-variables)

**Principais Pontos:**

- Variáveis da classe são considerados estado do objeto
- Usar uma variável de instância implica em manter estado entre duas chamadas de método. Se o valor armazenado em `C` não precisar viver entre duas chamadas então a variável de instância não deve existir
- Quanto menor o escopo léxico e tempo de vida de uma variável, menor a possibilidade de uso errôneo e melhor para a eliminação de recursos.

## [SOE: Instance variables vs parameter passing? Is there an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193052/instance-variables-vs-parameter-passing-is-there-an-argument)

**Principais pontos:**

- Do lado positivo, uso de variáveis de instância evitam a proliferação de parâmetros em métodos. A legibilidade de métodos com muitos argumentos é prejudicada. O livro [Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) argumenta que métodos não devem ter mais do que três parâmetros.
- Do lado negativo, uso de variáveis de instância apenas para evitar passá-las como parâmetro não é uma boa idéia e incha a classe.

## [Programmers: Ruby - when to use instance variables vs parameters between methods?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/214851/ruby-when-to-use-instance-variables-vs-parameters-between-methods)

**Principais pontos:**

- A decisão entre um estilo e outro depende do papel de `C` perante toda a classe `A`. Se a informação transportada em `C` é relevante para a maior parte da classe, então faz sentido ter uma variável de instância. **Exemplo:** Um objeto representando uma conta do banco que necessita do titular para quase todas as ações.
- Por outro lado, se os dados são específicos para determinado método (e métodos auxiliares) eles devem "viajar" como parâmetros ou objetos intermediários.