# O que é e quais as vantagens do Currying?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem, programação-funcional

Este é um conceito muito difundido em linguagens funcionais, mas o que ele é exatamente?

Por que é vantajoso?

*Bônus point*: É possível usá-lo em linguagens não funcionais? Ou mais genericamente, em linguagens que não possuem facilidades específicas? Pode dar algum exemplo? E as mesmas vantagens se aplicariam?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Currying e partial application

É extremamente comum encontrar por aí definições e exemplos de currying que na verdade se referem a [*partial function application*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), ou aplicação parcial de funções. Para quem, como eu, se interessa por programação funcional sem dominar de fato nenhuma linguagem puramente funcional, geralmente os dois conceitos ficam ainda mais confusos. Vou tentar explicar a diferença enquanto aproveito para consolidar meu próprio entendimento do assunto. Todos os meus exemplos usam JavaScript, mas imagino que sejam compreensíveis para quem usa C, Java, C#, entre outras linguagens.

#### Partial application

Em linguagens funcionais, funções não são "invocadas", e sim "aplicadas" a seus argumentos. Funções também são conhecidas como "cidadãos de primeira classe" da linguagem, ou seja, podem ser atribuidas a variáveis, e interagem com outras funções podendo ser passadas como parâmetros ou retornadas.

Uma função é "parcialmente aplicada" quando é aplicada a somente uma parte dos parâmetros que espera, e retorna outra função que espera os parâmetros restantes. Então aplicação parcial é uma maneira de pegar uma função e fixar (ou, como [disse o Zuul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21242), "cravar") certos parâmetros.

Por exemplo, a seguinte função em JavaScript espera três parâmetros:

```js
function soma(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

// Duas maneiras diferentes de invocar: 
soma(1, 2, 3);               // 6
soma.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]); // 6
```

Vamos criar uma função que aplica `soma` parcialmente, ou seja, fixa o primeiro parâmetro e retorna uma função que espera os outros dois:

```js
function somap(a) {
    return function(b, c) {
        return soma(a, b, c)
    }
}

// Uso:
var somadois = somap(2);
somadois(3, 4); // 9
```

Essa operação pode ser generalizada para qualquer função:

```js
function partial(fn) {
    // Guarda argumentos após fn numa array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(null, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)));
    };
}

var somadois = partial(soma, 2);
somadois(3, 4); // 9
```

Na verdade, o JavaScript já suporta isso nativamente com método [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) que as funções possuem:

```js
var somadois = soma.bind(null, 2);
```

#### Currying

A definição de currying da [resposta do Zuul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21242) é precisa e sucinta (grifo meu):

> Currying é o nome dado à técnica de dividimos uma função que recebe vários argumentos numa série de funções cada uma lidando com **um** argumento da função inicial.

Repare que nosso exemplo acima não atende a essa definição, pois `partial(soma, 2)` retorna uma função que lida com **dois** argumentos de `soma`, e não um. Se a nossa função fizesse currying, teríamos de chamá-la assim para obter o resultado final:

```js
var somadois = curry(soma, 2);
somadois(3)(4); // 9
```

A utilidade prática disso em JavaScript (entre outras linguagens) é discutível. Há exemplos de usos justificados, porém na maioria dos casos não existe muita vantagem. Implementações de funções de currying [são](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html) [possíveis](http://extralogical.net/articles/currying-javascript.html) em JavaScript, mas não sem algumas limitações.

O currying é muito útil em linguagens que em que as funções são sempre unárias, ou seja, aceitam um único argumento. Nelas, o currying é justamente uma maneira de se implementar funções que aceitam mais de um argumento. E [certas linguagens implementam funções com múltiplos parâmetros usando currying internamente](http://alecbenzer.com/blog/currying-partial-application/). Desse link, os seguintes exemplos em OCaml são equivalentes:

```ml
let foo = fun a b ->
  a * a + b * b
```

e

```ml
let foo = fun a ->
  fun b ->
    a * a + b * b
```

Em OCaml, a primeira maneira de definir a função é apenas açúcar sintático para a segunda. Ambas produzem objetos função idênticos. E em ambos os casos a chamada é igual, por exemplo `foo 1 2` – que seria `foo(1)(2)` em JavaScript.

Encontrei [no Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/190938) um ponto de vista interessante sobre isso (em tradução livre):

> Para mim o currying é importante enquanto constructo teórico que permite considerar todas as funções como unárias, já que qualquer outra função pode ser reduzida a uma função dessas.

Answer (score 16):

[Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> é o nome dado à técnica de dividimos uma função que recebe vários argumentos numa série de funções cada uma lidando com um argumento da função inicial.

> De origens matemáticas, criado por [Moses Schönfinkel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Sch%C3%B6nfinkel) e mais tarde aperfeiçoado por [Haskell Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry).

Após aplicada a técnica de *Currying* uma função aceita o primeiro argumento da função original devolvendo uma função que aceita o segundo argumento da função original e assim sucessivamente até todos os argumentos estarem a ser trabalhados por funções individuais.

Em termos práticos, a vantagem de *Currying* é o facto de termos, especialmente em projectos grandes, funções que são chamadas múltiplas vezes com um ou mais parâmetros de valor igual entre elas. Com a técnica de *Currying* evita-se a repetição de código e/ou valores nos parâmetros.

## Exemplo Prático

[Ver no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/R6GD2/)

A framework de JavaScript [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> tem uma implementação de [Curry](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/curry/index.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que permite "cravar" parâmetros na função original e posteriormente passar um número infinito de parâmetros adicionais.

O exemplo prático que eles apresentam na documentação demonstra bem a utilização e vantagem de *Currying*:

```js
// Função de exemplo para fazer "alert" do argumentos
function showArguments() {
  alert($A(arguments).join(', '));
}

// Vai gerar um "alert" de três argumentos "1, 2, 3"
showArguments(1, 2, 3);

/* "cravar" três argumentos em f e passar mais dois, resultando numa função
 * com 5 argumentos 3 dos quais comuns a outras funções
 * alerta "1, 2, 3, a, b"
 */
var f = showArguments.curry(1, 2, 3);
f('a', 'b');
```

Tendo `f` com 3 argumentos Curry, podemos chamar-la novamente sem ter que os repetir, poupando assim a referida repetição de código e argumentos:

```js
// alerta "1, 2, 3, c, d"
f('c', 'd');
```

---

## Saber mais

Pode-se ler mais sobre este assunto não só nos links já fornecidos mas também nas respostas dadas a estas perguntas no SOEN:

- [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314/352449)
- [In functional programming what is “currying”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1352855/352449)