# O que há de errado com a minha versão de map para um array em JS?

Tags: javascript

```
var kiko = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var forEach = function(array, newArray, action){
     for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        var newArray = [];
        newArray.action(array[i]);
    };   
};

forEach(kiko, newKiko, push)
newKiko
```

Estou estudando funções abstratas, e me deparei com um exemplo do livro Eloquent Javascript em que uma versão de array.map é criada do zero. Tentei fazer a minha, que varre um array, e cria outro array a cada item por que passa. Estou recebendo o erro "Push is not defined" mas é um método nativo de arrays em JS. O que pode estar dando errado?

Tentei uma segunda variação, mas essa me entrega um array vazio:

```
var kiko = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var forEach = function(array, action){
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        action(array[i]);
    };   
};


forEach(kiko, function(element){  
    var newKiko = [];
    newKiko.push(element);
})

newKiko
```

Comment: `push` é uma função do `Array`, não é uma função global. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: O newKiko é um array! Não funciona com ele?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu primeiro código, você está tentando escolher um método dinamicamente, mas o operador `.` não é a maneira correta de fazer isso. Quando você faz `objeto.algo` ele sempre procura uma propriedade/método com o nome `algo`, não interessa se existe ou não uma variável chamada assim. Para escolher um método de um objeto a partir do seu nome, é necessário usar strings e colchetes:

```
var action = "push";
...
newArray[action](...);
```

Isso te dá certa flexibilidade, desde que o par `(newArray, action)` seja consistente (i.e. `action` sempre possua o nome de um método de `newArray` que receba um argumento). Por outro lado, isso te obriga a usar sempre um objeto, não dá pra usar uma função isolada.

Seu segundo código, por outro lado, está perfeito (a definição, não a chamada, como apontado pelas demais respostas), quer dizer, perfeito para um `forEach` (para um `map`, ver [a resposta do bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68529/215)). Se você quiser chamar com uma função isolada, você chama, se você quiser chamar com um método de um objeto, você "liga" esse método ao objeto através da função [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (ou talvez com algum outro tipo de [*currying*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21215/215)):

```
var newKiko = [];

var push = Array.prototype.push;
// ou:
var push = newKiko.push;

var boundPush = push.bind(newKiko); // Fixa o "this" da função

...

boundPush(10); // Faz o mesmo que: newKiko.push(10)
```

Exemplos:

```js
var kiko = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var forEach = function(array, action){
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        action(array[i]);
    };   
};

// Chamando com uma função qualquer
var newKiko = [];
forEach(kiko, function(element){  
    newKiko.push(element);
})
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + JSON.stringify(newKiko) + "</p>";

// Chamando com um método de um objeto
var newKiko2 = [];
forEach(kiko, newKiko2.push.bind(newKiko2));
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + JSON.stringify(newKiko2) + "</p>";
```

E a propósito, o erro na chamada que mencionei anteriormente foi re-criar a lista `newKiko` dentro da função usada como *callback* - o primeiro exemplo acima mostra a maneira correta de chamar o código que você escreveu.

Answer (score 6):

As outras respostas são muito boas, mas faltou dizer uma coisa: por que raios você quer criar uma função de `map` e chama ela de `forEach`? São duas coisas diferentes! E é muito importante que o nome da função represente bem o que ela faz. A ideia de um *foreach* é apenas iterar sobre uma lista, como a função da [resposta do Maicon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68489/74). Se a sua intenção é fazer mapear uma array para outra, chame a função de `map` mesmo.

Sobre a implementação, eu gosto bastante da [versão do livro](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_lJEtQ+qjXz) que você citou (ótimo livro, aliás):

```
function map(array, transform) {
  var mapped = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    mapped.push(transform(array[i]));
  return mapped;
}
```

Repare que ela não recebe a array de saída, ela cria essa array e retorna. Talvez você tenha uma formação anterior em C, onde é comum passar um ponteiro para uma array de saída, mas em JS isso raramente seria uma boa solução.

Answer (score 5):

Para responder à tua pergunta do que está a falhar no teu código:

1- a tua função não retorna nada, está a correr meio sem sentido. Depois do ciclo `for` tens de dar `return newArray;`

2- o método `push` é um método de Array e não disponivel no escopo global. Podes "copiá-lo" mas tens de chamar `Array.prototype.push`. Depois quando usares tens de usar `.call)` assim:

```
function teste(arr, action) {
    action.call(arr, 3);
}
var foo = [1, 2];
teste(foo, Array.prototype.push);
console.log(foo); // dá [1, 2, 3]
```

3- quando usas `var newArray = [];` dentro do ciclo `for` estás a apagar a array e a começar de novo. Podes remover essa linha.

O código corrigido poderia ser assim: http://jsfiddle.net/chqv0zxy/

```
var kiko = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var forEach = function (array, newArray, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        action.call(newArray, array[i]);
    };
    return newArray;
};

var newKiko = forEach(kiko, [], Array.prototype.push)
console.log(newKiko); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

ou se não usares `return` mas sim passando a array por referência: http://jsfiddle.net/chqv0zxy/1/

```
var kiko = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var forEach = function (array, newArray, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        action.call(newArray, array[i]);
    };
};
var newArray = [];
forEach(kiko, newArray, Array.prototype.push)
console.log(newArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

No primeiro exemplo a função `push` não está definida porque ela é exclusiva do [`Array`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp). Não é uma função global.

No seu segundo exemplo o erro está aqui:

```
forEach(kiko, function(element){  
    var newKiko = []; /* <-- aqui */
    newKiko.push(element);
})
```

Você está limpando o array toda vez que ele passa no `for`. O correto seria:

```
var kiko = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var newKiko = []; /* coloca aqui */

var forEach = function(array, action){
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        action(array[i]);
    };   
};


forEach(kiko, function(element){  
    newKiko.push(element);
})

newKiko
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Maicon! Não existe jeito de eu fazer com que a própria função crie esse novo array? Assim eu não dependeria sempre da declaração do array vazio antes de defini-la?

Comment: @Kvera Mas o que ele faria com esse array novo que a função criou? Guardaria numa global? (argh!) Fazer isso é fácil, basta colocar um `if` dentro da função e, se a variável estiver indefinida ou nula, criar, senão não criar. Mas *onde guardar o resultado*, esse é o X da questão (por isso sou da opinião que uma declaração explícita é melhor).

Comment: Eu divido da mesma opinião que o @mgibsonbr