# Função de descobre maior valor entre variaveis JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções, formulário, if

Tenho o seguinte form:

```
<body> 
    <form name="questao1" method="post" onsubmit="sendToDB();"> 
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Enfermagem" onclick="getPontos(1)"> Garantir a saúde das pessoas 
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Eletroeletronica" onclick="getPontos(2)"> Máquinas e instalações elétricas 
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Informatica" onclick="getPontos(3)"> Usar lógica para fazer programas e sistemas
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Alimentos" onclick="getPontos(4)"> Desenvolver, gerenciar e distribuir produtos alimenticios
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Plasticos" onclick="getPontos(5)"> Desenvolver, gerenciar e distribuir produtos plásticos
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Logistica" onclick="getPontos(6)"> Desenvolver, gerenciar e distribuir produtos
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Administracao" onclick="getPontos(7)"> Gerenciar e influenciar pessoas a atingirem metas
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Quimica" onclick="getPontos(8)"> Estudar, manusear e transformar substâncias ou materiais
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Meio_Ambiente" onclick="getPontos(9)"> Estudar, manusear e transformar substâncias ou materiais da natureza
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Mecatronica" onclick="getPontos(10)"> Projetar, usar, instalar e controlar máquinas industriais
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Eletronica" onclick="getPontos(11)"> Sistemas  e aparelhos eletrônicos
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Telecomunicacao" onclick="getPontos(12)"> Sistemas e aparelhos de comunicação
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Seguranca" onclick="getPontos(13)"> Instruir e garantir a segurança das pessoas e locais
        <br><br><input type="submit" value="Próximo" onclick="finalizar()">     
    </form>
</body>
```

Que executa as funções

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
        efmg = 0; 
        eltelt = 0;
        info = 0;
        alm = 0;
        pltc = 0;
        log = 0;
        adm = 0;
        qmc = 0;
        ma = 0;
        resultado = 0;
            function getPontos(pontos){
                if (pontos == 1){ efmg = efmg + 1; }   
                if (pontos == 2){ eltelt = eltelt +1; }
                if (pontos == 3){ info = info + 1; } 
                if (pontos == 4){ alm = alm + 1;}  
                if (pontos == 5){ pltc = pltc + 1; }   
                if (pontos == 6){ log = log + 1; }  
                if (pontos == 7){ adm = adm + 1; }
                if (pontos == 8){ qmc = qmc +1; }
                if (pontos == 9){ ma = ma +1; }   
                if (pontos == 10){ mectron = mectron + 1; }     
                if (pontos == 11){ elt = elt + 1; }       
                if (pontos == 12){ tlcon = tlcon + 1; }         
                if (pontos == 13){ st = st + 1; }                     
            }      
            function finalizar(efmg,eltelt,info,alm,pltc,log,adm,qmc,ma,mectron,elt,tlcon,st){  
                if (efmg>eltelt){alert('Enfermagem');}else{alert('Eletroeletronica');} 
            }
```

Ela está funcionando corretamente, porém a função `finalizar()` compara apenas dois valores.

Existe alguma função em JavaScript que possa comparar todos esses valores sozinha e encontrar o maior entre eles (como a função `max()` em PHP)? Pois não é nem um pouco viável comparar com `if` todas as variáveis para encontrar o resultado.

Comment: Existe a função `max()`, mas onde entraria nesse código? Não parece que ele precisa desta função.

Comment: na parte de finalizar, pra encontrar o maior valor que foi atribuido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou fazer uma melhoria no código original, mas não acho seja o ideal, só não quero mudar demais sua estrutura. Pode testar, está funcionando como deseja.

Não precisa ter várias variáveis para depois transformar em *array* para achar o maior, já pode criar o *array* logo de início, assim vai acumulando os *clicks* em cada elemento do *array* em apenas uma linha, assim como a declaração da variável só precisa de uma linha. A finalização também precisa de apenas uma linha:

```js
var arrayPontos = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
function arrayPositionMax(array) {
    var max = -Infinity;
    var position = -Infinity;
    for (i = 0; i != array.length; ++i) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
            position = i;
        }
    }
    return position;
}
function getPontos(pontos){
    arrayPontos[pontos]++;
}      
function finalizar(){  
    alert(["Enfermagem", "Eletroeletronica", "Informatica", "Alimentos", "Plasticos", "Logistica", "Administracao", "Quimica", "Meio_Ambiente", "Mecatronica", "Eletronica", "Telecomunicacao", "Seguranca"][arrayPositionMax(arrayPontos) - 1]); 
}
```

```html
<form name="questao1" method="post" onsubmit=""> 
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Enfermagem" onclick="getPontos(1)"> Garantir a saúde das pessoas 
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Eletroeletronica" onclick="getPontos(2)"> Máquinas e instalações elétricas 
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Informatica" onclick="getPontos(3)"> Usar lógica para fazer programas e sistemas
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Alimentos" onclick="getPontos(4)"> Desenvolver, gerenciar e distribuir produtos alimenticios
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Plasticos" onclick="getPontos(5)"> Desenvolver, gerenciar e distribuir produtos plásticos
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Logistica" onclick="getPontos(6)"> Desenvolver, gerenciar e distribuir produtos
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Administracao" onclick="getPontos(7)"> Gerenciar e influenciar pessoas a atingirem metas
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Quimica" onclick="getPontos(8)"> Estudar, manusear e transformar substâncias ou materiais
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Meio_Ambiente" onclick="getPontos(9)"> Estudar, manusear e transformar substâncias ou materiais da natureza
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Mecatronica" onclick="getPontos(10)"> Projetar, usar, instalar e controlar máquinas industriais
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Eletronica" onclick="getPontos(11)"> Sistemas  e aparelhos eletrônicos
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Telecomunicacao" onclick="getPontos(12)"> Sistemas e aparelhos de comunicação
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Seguranca" onclick="getPontos(13)"> Instruir e garantir a segurança das pessoas e locais
    <br><br><input type="submit" value="Próximo" onclick="finalizar()">     
</form>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/MaxValueOption.js).

Se tiver dúvidas sobre o uso de *array* pode fazer perguntas específicas para aprender sobre o assunto.

---

A pergunta inicialmente não era clara do que queria, por isso a minha original e a outra resposta falavam simplesmente em pegar o máximo de *array*, quando na verdade o que precisava nem era bem um *array*, apesar de poder ser usado também. A solução originalmente escrita:

Não vi bem onde seria usado, mas basicamente eu faria assim, porque tem uma [performance melhor](https://jsperf.com/math-max-apply-vs-for).

```js
function arrayMax(array) {
    var max = -Infinity;
    for (i = 0; i != array.length; ++i) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
console.log(arrayMax([5, 8, 2, 3, 6, 1]));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/MaxValue.js).

Comment: Tem performance melhor porque não envolve chamada de método? O Math.max é nativo.

Comment: tentei asssim:    function arrayMax(Q1) {
                        var max = -Infinity;
                        for (i = 0; i != Q1.length; i++) {
                            if (Q1[i] > max) {
                                max = Q1[i];
                            }
                        }
                        return max;
                        if(max = emfg){alert('Enfermagem');}
                    } mas não funcionou :(

Comment: @bfavaretto Não conheço a implementação exata, mas acho que a culpa é do `apply` que ficará chamando o `max()` em cada elemento. Se é isto que quer dizer, então é. Tem uma resposta que fala algo sobre o conceito, se quiser dar uma lida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21298/101 :D

Comment: @RafaZanezi por isso que eu falei que não vi onde está querendo aplicar isto. Na verdade acho que todo esse código pode ser feito de outra forma.

Comment: @bigown Não conhecia essa resposta :D Pode ser, só vendo a implementação mesmo.

Comment: @bigown 
 
quero tratar das variáveis que estou somando + 1 a cada clique na checkbox. Esses valores estão sendo atribuídos à uma variável de acordo com a entrada nos dados 'pontos', quero pegar todas essas variáveis e comparar para descobrir qual das checkboxes o usuário mais selecionou.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/math-max-apply-vs-for

Comment: @RafaZanezi isso eu entendi, só não sei onde quer usar isto porque esse código está bem confuso. Tentei dar uma melhorada.

Comment: @bfavaretto usei seu link na resposta :P Obrigado. Praticamente fiz outra resposta porque parece ser isso que ele quer mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

Existe a função [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```js
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
console.log(getMaxOfArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]));
```

No seu caso é possível chamar a função `max` passando como argumento as variáveis:

```js
function finalizar(efmg, eltelt, info, alm, pltc, log, adm, qmc, ma, mectron, elt, tlcon, st) {
  return Math.max(efmg, eltelt, info, alm, pltc, log, adm, qmc, ma, mectron, elt, tlcon, st);
}

console.log(finalizar(3,1,2,4,5,6,12,8,2,1,3,5,9));
```

Comment: poderia me explicar como usa-la nesse caso?

Comment: Não ficou claro para mim sobre quais valores você quer obter o maior. Quais seriam?

Comment: quero tratar das variáveis que estou somando + 1  a cada clique na checkbox. Esses valores estão sendo atribuídos à uma variável de acordo com a entrada nos dados 'pontos', quero pegar todas essas variáveis e comparar para descobrir qual das checkboxes o usuário mais selecionou.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta @RafaZanezi

Comment: nesse caso, eu poderia atribuir o Max.math à uma variavel? Exemplo: resultado = Math.max(efmg, eltelt, info, alm, pltc, log, adm, qmc, ma, mectron, elt, tlcon, st);

Comment: Sim, sem dúvida!

Comment: tentei fazer isso mas quando usei em: if(resultado == efmg){alert('Enfermagem');}else{alert('Não sei');} e testei selecionando apenas a opção de infermagem, ele sempre retorna 'Não sei' xP

Comment: Mas o efmg era o maior valor quando fez o caso de teste?

Comment: sim, era, sim... Depois tentei o seguinte:  alert(Math.max(efmg, eltelt, info, alm, pltc, log, adm, qmc, ma, mectron, elt, tlcon, st)); para exibir qual o maior valor, porém ele retornou 'Nan'.

Comment: NaN é not a number, significa que provavelmente você estava enviando uma string. Se você puder atualizar a pergunta com o novo código fica mais fácil ajudar :)

Comment: Ok, acabei de atualizar :)